# How to make bibtex issue a meaningful error message if it is run instead of biber?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber, auxiliary-files

Suppose I have a custom class that requires the use of `biblatex`, and moreover with the `biber` backend (`\RequirePackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`). Even though the documentation of this class states these requirements, everybody knows that nobody reads documentations.

People using this class will be notified if `biblatex` is missing:

> LaTeX Error: File `biblatex.sty' not found.

and are likely to understand that they have to install it. But, about the `biber` requirement, things are much less clear. Indeed, a warning appears at the end of the *latex compilation:

> ```
> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
> (biblatex)                test
> (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
> ```

but everybody knows that nobody reads the warnings (which are often not highlighted by the TeX editors). Therefore, these people are likely to run `bibtex` instead of `biber`, and the error message they will face is not informative at all:

> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2021)
> The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
> I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
> I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
> (There were 3 error messages)
> ```

Here is an example (simplified, without any custom class involved) to play with the above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{knuth:ct:a}
\end{document}
```

My question is: is it possible for the class to add something to the `.aux` file (on which `bibtex` is run) in order `bibtex` issues a more informative error message in case it is run instead of `biber`?

Comment: You could do `\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\bibstyle{Run-biber-instead-of-bibtex!}}`, admittedly not a nicely formatted error message, but it prints the relevant info...

Answer (score 1):

The only way to properly control what BibTeX does is via a `.bst` file. All other behaviour is hard-coded. In particular, BibTeX will just try to process the entries indicated in the `.aux` with `\citation` from the `.bib` files indicated with `\bibdata` according to the `.bst` file indicated with `\bibstyle`. BibTeX will throw an error if `\bibdata` or `\bibstyle` is missing, but that is about it.

So one idea would be to create a dummy `.bst` file to try and inject a more useful error message into the output. We would tell BibTeX to use this `.bst` file when it encounters our `.aux` file.

As far as I can see, you cannot throw an error with arbitrary text in a `.bst` file. You can issue warnings, though.

The most minimal setup for the `.bst` file that I could find is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{run-biber-error.bst}
ENTRY { dummy } {} {}

READ

FUNCTION {printwarning} {
  "You need to run Biber instead of BibTeX" warning$
}

EXECUTE {printwarning}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibstyle{run-biber-error}}}
\makeatother


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{knuth:ct:a}
\end{document}
```

this produces

> ```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.12.10)
> The top-level auxiliary file: mabsssshg.aux
> The style file: run-biber-error.bst
> I found no \citation commands---while reading file mabsssshg.aux
> I found no \bibdata command---while reading file mabsssshg.aux
> Warning--You need to run Biber instead of BibTeX
> (There were 2 error messages)
> ```

Comment: Nice! But too bad we cannot issue an error message :$ What would be also useful is to drop the error lines ‟no `\citation` commands” and ‟no `\bibdata` command” in order to make the important message to have more chances to be read.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Well, if you drop both of them (which you probably can if you add dummy calls and a dummy file with dummy entries), then you will only get a warning. And nobody reads warnings...